# Delphi 7 indy web server display AResponseInfo.PostStream

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, indy

I have some clients that post xml / soap containers. I would like to build a tiny standalone indy web server app, that accepts any request and displays the content of the PostStream in a memo field. Unfortunately I don't know how to decode the PostStream. I get an exception using this code:

```
ARequestInfo.PostStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
Memo1.Lines.LoadFromStream(ARequestInfo.PostStream);
```

I am using Delphi7 Enterprise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every request type uses the `PostStream` property, so you have to check if the `PostStream` is not `nil` before you attempt to use it.

Also, `TIdHTTPServer` is a multi-threaded component.  Its events are triggered in worker threads, and it is not safe to access UI components from outside of the main thread, so you need to synchronize with the main thread when accessing the `TMemo`.

**Update:**  If you need to always have a `PostStream` available, in older versions of Indy you can use the `OnCreatePostStream` event to create your own `TStream` object to use as the `PostStream`. In those versions, `TIdHTTPServer` manages `PostStream` objects that it creates, and sometimes frees them before giving them to you, but user-defined `PostStream` objects are not freed until after the request is finished being processed by you.  However, in recent Indy 10 releases, there is a new `OnDoneWithPostStream` event that helps control when a `PostStream` gets freed for any given request, regardless of whether it is created by `TIdHTTPServer` or by you (in which case, you don't need to use the `OnCreatePostStream` event to extend the `PostStream`'s lifetime).  In all versions, an unfreed `PostStream` is always freed when the `TIdHTTPRequestInfo` object is freed.

Comment: My goal would be just to display all incoming requests and all content in the Memo field. So if something is posted, I would like to see what was posted. I just know the PostStream, what else is there? Thanks a lot

Comment: Sometimes the posted data is parsed into the `TIdHTTPRequestInfo.FormParams` and `TIdHTTPRequestInfo.UnparsedParams` properties instead.